# Post-build trigger different for manually triggered builds and timer-triggered builds

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Simplified, I have a "build release" (BR) project in Jenkins that checks out and builds code, and a "full-blown test" (FBT) project that tests this code.

At night, a BR project is triggered by a timer, and I need the BR project to trigger the FBT project when it's done. However, if I trigger a BR project manually, I *don't* want the FBT project to be triggered afterwards, because that takes too much resources from the build server.

Is there a way to achieve this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways to solve this problem:

Solution 1

1. Add a parameter to your BR project, a boolean called TriggerFBT.  Default value is CHECKED.
2. In the BR project, use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to check the TriggerFBT parameter.  If eanbled, add a build step ([Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)) to run the FBT job.  Note that you want it as a BUILD STEP, not as a post-build/publish sort of thing.

When you manually trigger the BR job, you'll need to remember to uncheck the TriggerFBT parameter.  Because TriggerFBT is checked by default, when the BR project is triggered via timer, the FBT project will eventually get triggered.

Solution 2

1. Remove the timer trigger from the BR project.
2. Create a new job - call it TimerBR.  Add the timer trigger to TimerBR.
3. In the build steps, use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to first execute the BR project, wait for it finish, then execute the FBT project.